# Spanish-language chapter and bibliography headings (cambio de Palabras Bibliografy y Chapter por Bibliografía y Capitulos)

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, babel, languages, spanish

Buenos días,
Tengo un problema, estoy trabajando en una plantilla que fue diseñada en ingles, y hasta ahora ha sido bueno trabajar en ella, pero necesito pasar todo a español, he sido capaz de pasar todo a español, solo me falta por pasar dos comandos, el comando \bibliography y \chapter, quisiera saber como puedo pasarlos a español para que en la tesis me aparezca Bibliografía y Capitulo1, Capitulo 2, muchas gracias

Hello,
I have problem: I am working with a template that was designed in English, and up till now it has worked fine, but I need to change everything to Spanish. I am capable of translating everything except for two commands, `\bibliography` and `\chapter`. I would like to know how to adapt these commands for Spanish so that in my thesis they will produce "Bibliografía" and "Capítulo 1", "Capítulo 2". Thank you.

Comment: Buenos días, y bienvenido a [TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) English is the shared language we use on this site. Could you please translate your question?

Comment: Boenos. *plantilla* is a word i learned just now. I don't like it. Templates are bad in general. Please translate your question to english and add a minimal working example to it. A link to the template would also be useful.

Comment: If the template is reasonable then the `babel` package should do most of the renaming for you (`\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`). Please add a small complete document to your posting such that we see which class and packages are involved.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents} % para crear bibliografía por ejemplo
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Calderon:VidaSueno,
author={Calderón de la Barca, Pedro},
title={La vida es sueño},
location={Madrid},
publisher={Cátedra},
year=2000
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % para usar accentos como así

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
  % cambia "Chapter"->"Capítulo" y "Bibliography"->"Bibliografía"

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % para la bibliografía en este ejemplo

\begin{document}
\chapter{Primero}
Una cita.\cite{Calderon:VidaSueno}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the information given in the question, your answer is pure guesswork and might only coonfuse the OP. The chance that the template really uses biblatex is low.